# "#grid > .core is undefined" when lessc compile bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

i got the following error when i ran `lessc bootstrap.less`

```
at less.Parser.parser.parse.i (/Users/ftiasch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:385:31): #grid > .core is undefined (Less::ParseError)
from /Users/ftiasch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less/parser.rb:61:in `block in to_css'
from /Users/ftiasch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:90:in `block in do_lock'
from /Users/ftiasch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:88:in `call'
from /Users/ftiasch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:88:in `Locker'
from /Users/ftiasch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:88:in `do_lock'
from /Users/ftiasch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:60:in `lock'
from /Users/ftiasch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:30:in `exec'
from /Users/ftiasch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less/java_script.rb:26:in `exec'
from /Users/ftiasch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less/parser.rb:61:in `to_css'
from /Users/ftiasch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/less-2.2.2/bin/lessc:99:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/ftiasch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/lessc:19:in `load'
from /Users/ftiasch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/lessc:19:in `<main>'
from /Users/ftiasch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /Users/ftiasch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

i have found [this issue](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2620). but i have got my lessc upgraded to 1.3.

here is the version:

```
lessc -v
```

lessc 1.3.0 (LESS Compiler) [Ruby] 2.2.2

the bootstrap source file are cloned from github.

Comment: Same problem here. lessc 1.3.0, bootstrap from github source 2.3.0

Comment: same problem but I'm running `lessc` using node: `1.3.0 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript]`

Comment: `Bootstrap 2.3.0` from Github source compiled with `lessc 1.3.0` also failed for me, but worked after upgrading to `lessc 1.3.3`. (Note I then had problems with my @Import statements - using a Windows box I had to convert / to \\)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to **upgrade less to version 1.3.3**.

Example (if you're running **less** from within node.js)

```
sudo npm install -g less
```

Comment: the ruby wrapper of lessc seems a bit of out-dated. so that it's better to use less.js instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

1. Go to [the less.js repo](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/tree/v1.3.3) and download the repo as a zip file
2. Go to [this branch of the less.rb repo](https://github.com/populr/less.rb/tree/v2.2.2-less1.3.3) and download the repo as a zip file
3. Replace /Users/ftiasch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less/loader.rb with the version of that file from the repo in step 2 (lib/less/loader.rb)
4. Replace the contents of /Users/ftiasch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less/js/ with the contents of the repo from step 1

That should do it! Two things to note:

1. When I implemented this solution, I was using ruby 1.9.3-p385
2. Replacing the contents of /Users/ftiasch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/less-2.2.2/ with the contents of the repo from step 2 DID NOT WORK for me. It would've been nice if it did...